# How can I test my bluetooth code with only one device?

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth

I'm writing a program with bluetooth connectivity in Python. I only have the one laptop to test with. Using code or software, how can I simulate bluetooth connections?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to simulate physical connections. You have to use an external device in order to test the connection.

Comment: I agree with @OsmanEsen, so you might want to invest in a Raspberry Pi.